# What does [Function: bound ] mean when node debugging?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I `node debug` my .js file and I `catch(error) {`

when I `console.dir(error)` it just says

`[Function: bound ]`

What is going on?
How do I get the full error object?
How do I get the stack trace?

Comment: Random guess...try `console.dir(error.stack)`

Comment: Please provide more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is going on?

`[Function: bound]` seems to be a bound function object, i.e. the result of a [`.bind()` call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

> How do I get the full error object? How do I get the stack trace?

Not at all. You don't get these if you're not throwing `Error` objects. You'll need to find the code that (unwittingly?) throws a function object and fix it.

Comment: If the error is coming somewhere from inside the nest of 3rd party libraries I use what should I do to find it?

Comment: @Richard: Just file an upstream bug :-) Or if you feel comfortable with it, throw a debugger at the library or inject your own try-catch-statements into its code to find the source of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

im taking a shot in the dark here but try

```
         callback(success, err): ....if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
         console.log(err)
```